# excel vba - Macro to copy filtered data on cell change

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to do the following:

- from Sheet1 watch the A column for the data I input;
- when I write something in a cell in the A column use that value to filter Sheet2;
- after the filter is done, copy everything except the column header from the second sheet into the first one, even if there are multiple values;
- as a bonus it could copy everything except from column A from Sheet2 and copy starting from Column B in Sheet1, which is what I attempted.

I tried writing this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed. New value is: " _
            & Target.Value
        copy_filter (Target)
    End If
End Sub

Sub copy_filter(Changed)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("$A$1:$L$5943")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Changed.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Copy
        End With
    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Changed.Address).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The first `Private Sub` watches for change events on Sheet1, I put it into the sheet module, not the Workbook module, and it works, since the box gets shown correctly, however on the second `Sub` I get an error on this line: `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Changed.Value`, the error says: `Run-time error '424': Object required`.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `copy_filter (Target)` to either

`call copy_filter (Target)`

OR

`copy_filter Target`

Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. However I encountered a couple more issues: whenever I copy the header row gets copied as well, but the `.Offset(1, 0)` cuts the header and 1 additional row, also the `Selection.Rows.Count` parameter returns 1 in every case, despite some being multiple lines selected. This makes it impossible to `.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1`.